# How to assign a unique ID to each instance of a task in Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

If I have four instances of, say, an appserver running in Amazon ECS.

Is there some way to let each appserver that it is #1 of four, #2 of four, and so on.

I've read these docs [Amazon ECS container metadata file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html), but there doesn't seem to be anything like that mentioned in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `task-arn` from the [ECS metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html) identifies the individual running container task:

```
  aws_metadata=$(curl -s "$ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4")
  aws_task_arn=$(echo "$aws_metadata" | jq -r '.Labels["com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn"]')
  aws_task_id=$(echo "$aws_task_arn" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
```

When run in the container, as an ECS service defined with two tasks, executing on the same EC2 instance - each container was executed with different values of `aws_task_id`.

Whether this is "unique" enough for your purposes depends on your use-case.  I don't know if these values are guaranteed unique - they might be re-used, or re-used across different ECS services, etc.

For myself, all I'm trying to do is uniquely identify the tasks that are executing simultaneously for a particular ECS Service that is servicing requests for my API.

I can't say if this is actually guaranteed to be unique, but I think it'll be good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerInstance.html
if you are referencing an id for each *instance*, it is this: **ec2InstanceId**, because what you are seeing in the metadata you presented is the id of the container within this deployed instance, not the *instance*.

Comment: Multiple ECS containers can be running on the same EC2 instance - `ec2InstanceId` is not a unique identifier for an individual task container.